Angular ng-recaptcha aparece recortado en versión móvil
tengo un problema con el que esperaría que me pudieran ayudar. En angular 16 tengo un formulario reactivo y estoy tratando de usar ng-recaptcha, pero al visualizarse el captcha en la página aparece recortado y no se ve bien.

Cómo ven, se visualiza recortado por alguna razóm.
<div class="mb-4">
<re-captcha siteKey="{{captchaSiteKey}}" formControlName="recaptchaReactive" />
</div>

Por lo que he visto el re-captcha en si mismo no se puede estilizar, pero sí se puede el iframe en el que se encuentra o el contenedor que envuelve el captcha.
He intentado aplicar transform scale y otros estilos, pero lo único que consigo es que el captcha se vea más pequeño pero aun así esté recortado:

Agradezco cualquier luz sobre el tema, llevo un tiempo dándole vueltas y no encuentro solución
UPDATE: Esto solamente ocurre en la versión web para móviles, en la versión web de escritorio el captcha se ve correctamente
